# Are there beliefs that are non-propositional?

Tags: belief

What, if they exist, are non-propositional beliefs? Are beliefs Propositionalised representations by definition, or can they exist in other forms?

Would they just exist as a memory of raw sense data / Qualia experienced by someone, after receiving stimuli (visual, auditory etc)?

Comment: "*Most contemporary philosophers characterize belief as a “propositional attitude”*", says [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/belief/), so that would be a no for the most. Even defectors associate them with something propositional-ish, e.g. in [Buchanan, Is Belief a Propositional Attitude?](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/p/pod/dod-idx/is-belief-a-propositional-attitude.pdf?c=phimp;idno=3521354.0012.001;format=pdf) it is "*a restricted proposition-type... gappy structure... together with a vague range of restrictions on how [it] is to be completed*". Raw data is junk until interpreted.

Comment: @Conifold So for example, if one was to walk into a room with a cube on the floor, perceive said cube, then subsequently exit the room (without having "propositionalised" that experience), what would that awareness of the cube be called? Would the Raw Data attained just be considered memory or something more?

Comment: @Conifold In the same way, suppose one walked through a maze, and during the process they gradually gained a mental map of said maze until they eventually completed it. They then go through the maze again are able to complete perfectly. What would it be called, if during every bifurcation, they were "aware" of the correct path to the exit? Would it just be termed "aware"?

Comment: Where there is "awareness" there is more than raw data. Neural network does not function like a digital computer with separate storage, so any input has to be partially integrated into the network to register at all. Most will say that it is thereby propositionalized, perhaps vaguely, and "awareness" is a sign of it. The radical alternative is that no belief is formed at all, and we are dealing with non-propositional knowledge-how manifested in later actions. Buchanan's "gappy structure" is somewhere in between.

Comment: Is https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/content-nonconceptual/ relevant?